# Prevent ScrollView to focus on child elements during scrolling?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView in which I have a quite long form, mainly using EditText elements. The problem is, that when the user scrolls around in this form, ScrollView changes the focus constantly. It seemed to me, that it assigns focus to the first element on screen when the user stops touching the screen, and the fling motion triggers.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought that you can make EditText as non-focusable elements. And when user will click on any item in ListView you can make that particular element focusable again.